# Progress bar in Ajax Update panel not showing

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I wrote the following

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="Download" runat="server">
     <ContentTemplate>
         <asp:Label ID="lblMessage"  runat="server" 
           Text="Click the link to download the Report:"></asp:Label>  
         <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnDownload" runat="server"  
           OnClick="lbtnDownload_Click" Text="Download Excel Sheet"></asp:LinkButton> 
     </ContentTemplate>
     <Triggers>
         <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="lbtnDownload"/>
     </Triggers>
 </asp:UpdatePanel>

 <asp:UpdateProgress ID="download1" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="Download">
     <ProgressTemplate> 
         <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl"indicator.gif" " />  
     </ProgressTemplate>
 </asp:UpdateProgress>
```

But the progress bar image is not showing can any one tell why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the following: `<asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="lbtnDownload"/>`

Comment: Thanks it works can you tell what is the problem if i use that

Comment: UpdateProgress used for asynchronous postbacks but you have specify that the lbtnDownload button cause normal postback so whole page has refreshed.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, first thing to check is that you are definitely posting back successfully, also add a delay interval:

```
<asp:UpdateProgress DisplayAfter="0" ID="download1" runat="server"
   AssociatedUpdatePanelID="Download">
```

Comment: Still i am unable to display the image